# Goroutines prematurely go asleep

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

The code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    link := make(chan bool)
    stop := make(chan bool)
    go a(link, stop)
    go b(link)
    <-stop
}

func a(link chan bool, stop chan bool) {
    for i := 0; i < 20; i++ {
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        link <- true
    }
    stop <- true
}

func b(link chan bool) {
    go func() {
        <-link
        fmt.Println("A")
    }()
    go func() {
        <-link
        fmt.Println("B")
    }()
}
```

This code does nothing in particular, I'm just trying to understand channels and goroutines. But something is wrong and goroutines are asleep after two loops and application crashes.

Let's analyze what it does - every one second message is send to `link`. Function `b` receives it in two places, so `print` A and B is called. So basically every one second A and B should appear in console. But for reasons unknown to me it doesn't happen, program prints A and B once, and then crashes.
I probably don't understand the concept well enough (golang is really unintuitive), so I hope I can get an answer here.

Comment: You try to send 20 values through `link`, but you only ever receive 2. The crash happens because you have a simple deadlock that can be detected when no goroutine can proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A channel send to an unbuffered channel will only succeed if there is a goroutine receiving from it. For the first two sends, there are goroutines receiving from the `link` channel. But they receive one value and terminate, and there are no longer any goroutines receiiving from `link`, so the third send to `link` blocks. Since there are no other goroutines running, program deadlocks.

Answer (score -1):

The main problem in your code is when you receive a **first** message through `link` channel in function `b` - you **exit** the goroutine, so you do not listen to the publisher. So you need to "*subscribe*" to the channel. You can do it via `range`, like:

```
for _ = range link {
    fmt.Println("A")
}
```

It will listen to the channel until you close it: `close(link)`, then it will exit.

Also, you can do it using `for` `select` combination, as it described [here](https://go.dev/tour/concurrency/5)